# What is the best workflow to migrate a site using domain access?

Tags: migrations, domain-access

i have a site with 20 subdomains using the [domain access module](https://drupal.org/project/domain) on a dev server and i want to migrate them to a production server.

There is only a change from

> subdomain.maindomain.eu

to

> subdomain.maindomain.de

What is the best to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a little more specific, are you just wanting to migrate the whole database to a new installation or are you migrating content into an existing installation

In the first case it should be fairly simple,

- Put your site in maintenance mode and then flush all the caches.
- Take a backup of your sites directory.
- Copy the database to the new server.
- Upload the drupal installation and then the sites directory to your new server
- Modify the settings.php to connect to the database on the new server.
- Using a DB admin tool such as phpmyadmin modify the "domain" table in the database on the new server, there is a field in this table called "subdomain" this relates to the url of your domains so just modify this to suit your needs.

Comment: yes i want to move to whole installation to a new server with .de domain. i was unsure about how to change the domain settings on the new server. i will take a look modifieng the database directly. thx!